# My App Crashes but Works on Simulator

Tags: objective-c, logging, crash, ios-simulator

I updated my app, Dart Clicker to version 1.1 with some bug fixes and when I click the start button it crashes. I looked at the crash log using iPhone Configuration Utility and it showed this:

```
 May 18 13:04:48 Maanits-5S DartClicker[414] <Error>: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSURL initFileURLWithPath:]: nil string parameter'
        *** First throw call stack:
        (0x18bdfaf50 0x1983041fc 0x18bdfae90 0x18c8ef180 0x18c8ef0ec 0x1000077d4 0x18ec786b4 0x10000a4c4 0x18edc4670 0x18edc43f4 0x18ee43194 0x18ee430cc 0x18eebb614 0x18eeb9a9c 0x18edf90c8 0x18edf905c 0x18ede2538 0x18edf8a5c 0x18edf86f0 0x18edf3388 0x18edc4b68 0x18edc2c58 0x18bdbb644 0x18bdba9a0 0x18bdb8c38 0x18bcf9c20 0x1919e1c0c 0x18ee2afdc 0x10000a834 0x1988f7aa0)
    May 18 13:04:48 Maanits-5S ReportCrash[416] <Notice>: ReportCrash acting against PID 414
    May 18 13:04:48 Maanits-5S backboardd[31] <Error>: HID: The 'Passive' connection 'AdSheet' access to protected services is denied.
    May 18 13:04:48 Maanits-5S limitadtrackingd[164] <Warning>: Not scheduling a new BTA job; keeping previously scheduled job should run after 82700s from now when the network is available.
    May 18 13:04:48 Maanits-5S ReportCrash[416] <Notice>: Formulating crash report for process DartClicker[414]
    May 18 13:04:48 Maanits-5S com.apple.launchd[1] (UIKitApplication:DartClicker.DartClicker[0x6233][414]) <Warning>: (UIKitApplication:DartClicker.DartClicker[0x6233]) Job appears to have crashed: Abort trap: 6
    May 18 13:04:48 Maanits-5S backboardd[31] <Warning>: Application 'UIKitApplication:DartClicker.DartClicker[0x6233]' exited abnormally with signal 6: Abort trap: 6
    May 18 13:04:48 Maanits-5S ReportCrash[416] <Notice>: Saved crashreport to /var/mobile/Library/Logs/CrashReporter/DartClicker_2014-05-18-130448_Maanits-5S.ips using uid: 0 gid: 0, synthetic_euid: 501 egid: 0
```

Is there a way to fix this? 
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you're passing nil to `initFileURLWithPath:`. I would need to see some code to find out why this is.

Comment: I just had one more question: This error occurred when my app was on the app store but it was working fine on the simulator so is there a way to test it without submitting it because it was already working on the simulator?

Comment: @MadMan30 There are certain differences between the simulator and an actual device. Some are more obvious than others, like camera and accelerometer. Some are not obvious at all, and that's why Apple encourages developers to try their app on a real device. If you don't have an iOS device you're out of luck unfortunately, until you get yourself a device that is. Perhaps you have a friend you can borrow from? I hope this answered your question.